# GoogleAppScript TeamDrives

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have this code :

```
var params = {
  supportsTeamDrives: true,
  includeTeamDriveItems: true
};

var pageToken

folders = Drive.Files.list({
  q: "title = 'ADSD'",
  maxResults: 100,
  pageToken: pageToken,
  params: {
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    includeTeamDriveItems: true
  }
});
```

But the result is

```
{kind=drive#fileList, etag="8xUCra6FbWx8e1S7QPWn-stRIsE/skD00QgZZ0FB6U5ufzrrxrFjqyA", incompleteSearch=false, items=[], selfLink=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=100&q=title+%3D+'ADSD'&alt=json}
```

However if I do the same request on here :

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list?authuser=1&apix_params=%7B%22includeTeamDriveItems%22%3Atrue%2C%22q%22%3A%22title%20%3D%20%27ADSD%27%22%2C%22supportsTeamDrives%22%3Atrue%7D#examples
```

I've got this self link :

```
"selfLink": ["https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?includeTeamDriveItems=true&q=title+%3D+'ADSD'&supportsTeamDrives=true"][1]
```

where includeTeamDriveItems and supportsTeamDrives are set to true

I don't know if that's the reason why one request succeeds (the one where you try the API) and the other doesn't (on Google App Script).

For the record, I enabled Google Drive Advanced Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The parameters must be in the request and not in "parameters".

```
var pageToken
  do {
    folders = Drive.Files.list({
      pageSize: 10,
      //fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
      includeTeamDriveItems: true,
      supportsTeamDrives: true,
      q: "title = 'ADSD'"
    });
    /*
    if (folders.items && folders.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < folders.items.length; i++) {
    var folder = folders.items[i];
    Logger.log('%s (ID: %s)', folder.title, folder.id);
    }
    } else {
    Logger.log('No folders found.');
    }*/
    Logger.log(folders);
    pageToken = folders.nextPageToken;
    //Logger.log(pageToken);
  } while (pageToken);
```